# Why self window opens in a new window?

Tags: asp.net

I have a hyperlink wrapping a button like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="LinkDownload" Target="_self"><asp:Button ID="Button_Send" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Download" /></asp:HyperLink>
```

After validating, the Button is visible. Why when I click on it, a new window is opened even though the Hyperlink is _self.

How can I make it such a way that it opens in the same window?

Comment: Why are you using a hyperlink and wrapping a button inside of it?

Comment: on your Target="_self" replace self to Target="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: the url is dynamically set in code-behind. Using hyperlink to wrap button, i can easily set the button visible/disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Button wrapped in side hyperlink doesn't look alright to me. You can try setting the url to hyperlink, I think that should work.

Alternate Options :

Just add the button and in its click handler do without hyperlink:

```
Response.Redirect("blah.aspx");
```

Alternatively you can write a line of javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Text" onclick="location='blah.aspx'" />
```